# Destroying a loader via LoaderManager throws an exception sometimes?

Tags: android

I need to destroy a loader, sometimes I'll get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:960)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:768)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.destroyLoader(LoaderManager.java:672)
at com.me.test.MyTest.test(MyTest.java:213)
```

I'm doing the following:

```
LoaderManager lm = ...;
Loader loader = ...;
lm.destroyLoader(loader.getId());
```

Does this mean that the loader could somehow already be gone or something? Anyone else see this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayeb the loader is holding a reference to a Context that has gone out of scope : does this happen when you've changed activity or loader ?

Comment: Hmm not sure, I've just seen a few reports of it, so not sure how users are triggering it. I'm using a ViewPager with fragments, though. It seems like it happens when they're swiping between tabs.

Comment: The loaders themselves aren't keeping any references to Contexts though I would guess? (at least I'm not)

Comment: I see all sorts of weird errors in Fragment stuff on some phones. I'm using the compatibility library. I've just ended up adding lots of try{} catch{} and hoping Google fixes it in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

No problems for me, either they updated library or this is the order it should be called in:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get NPE because you are not realising that `loaderManager.getLoader(id)` can return null if the loader is no longer present.

[Android Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) say:

> `public abstract Loader<D> getLoader (int id)`
>
> Return the Loader with the given id or null if no matching Loader is found.

So what you need is, is to add a null check like:

```
LoaderManager lm = ...;
Loader loader = ...;
if (loader != null) {    //this will fix you NPE
    lm.destroyLoader(loader.getId());
}
```

Or you may avoid all the fuss and do destroy the loader will following line of code:

```
lm.destroyLoader(LOADER_ID);
```